# PHP function not returning result

Tags: php, mysql, function, return

I have a function `loadContent()` that when called, queries a database, formats the data and should return the result. This is being used to build a very primitive CMS and this function is used to load the articles from the database.

Here is the function is question:

```
    $articles = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `name`, `content`, `keywords`, `description`, `access_level` FROM `tb_articles` WHERE `page_id`='$pageID'");
            if(!$articles){
                die('Error!: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            while($arts = mysql_fetch_assoc($articles)){
                $content .= '<div class="article" id="art-' . $arts['id'] . '">';
                $content .= '<h1>' . $arts['name'] . '</h1>';
                $content .= $arts['content'];
                $content .= '</div>';
            }
        return $content; 
    }else{
```

My problem is that nothing is being returned. The SQL is verified, it should return two rows. I have commented out everything in the loop and added the line `$content .= 'test';` and changed the return statement to `echo $content;` and the function successfully echo'ed "test" twice. So whats wrong with what I have done?

Thanks for helping me out, I'm pretty new to PHP.

**UPDATE:**

The post now represents all valid changes.

I got somewhere with `var_dump`. I dumped `$content` just before the `return` statement. All of the articles in the database (2 of them) were displayed inside of `string(2445) ""`. This confirms there are no problems with the query. I am now thinking it has something to do with the return statement.

Comment: I assume $arts is short for $articles, and in the real code one of those two variable names is being used consistently?

Comment: Try changing `$content = ` to `$content .= ` at the first row in your loop.

Comment: Ahhh... no, nevermind, I understand how it works.

Comment: Are you sure there is no `mysql_error`?

Comment: Are you actually using mysql_connect() elsewhere to connect to the DB?

Comment: Yes, the connection is working elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Why select the other columns when you don't use them?

Comment: I have confirmed there is no mysql_error.

Comment: @AlexLunix I plan to use all the columns, I just haven't gone any further since this much isn't working.

Comment: Ah, ok. The only explanation I can think of is that something is wrong with the result($articles), do a var_dump of it?

Comment: @AlexLunix I'm not familiar with that. Exactly where would I do that in my code?

Comment: var_dump dumps the contents and type of a variable, place var_dump($articles); after you run the query, if it's false than there were no results or there was an error.

Comment: @AlexLunix I did a `var_dump` on `$articles` and it was fine. Check the update above to see what happened when I dumped `$content`.

Comment: Whats the "}else{" at the end? Is there more to this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your code to this:

```
function loadContent(){
   $content = '';
   $pageID = 1;
   //
   $articles = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `name`, `content`, `keywords`, `description`, `access_level` 
                            FROM `tb_articles` 
                            WHERE `page_id`='$pageID'");

        // you only need the associative array
        while($arts = mysql_fetch_array($articles, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            // close your tag properly and use the concat operator
            $content .= '<div class="article" id="art-' . $arts['id'] . '">';
            $content .= '<h1>' . $arts['name'] . '</h1>';
            $content .= $arts['content'];
            $content .= '</div>';
        }

    return $content;

 }
```

Also you could try running `mysql_error()` after your call to `mysql_query()` to see if anything goes wrong.

Another thing that you should check is so that there actually is a row with page_id equal to 1 in your database. You should also make sure that your column names are correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't change anything.

Comment: @JohnA - And you have tried `echo mysql_error();` after your `mysql_query()` call? I updated my answer, not sure that it helps, but try to remove the `{` and `}` characters in your query.

Comment: I implimented this:if(!$articles){
     die('Error!: ' . mysql_error());
    }

Comment: +1 for the MYSQL_ASSOC part, very important so you don't get double results.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is related, but it doesn't look like you ever close the first `div` tag.  You don't close the id attribute quote either (opened with an apostrophe, and you concatenate a quote).

More specifically:

```
... id='art-" . $arts['id'] . "'></div>";
```

Comment: You are right about this, I corrected these issues but unfortunately I didn't solve my problem. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$content .= "<div class='article' id='art-" . $arts['id'] . '"';
```

and it should be

```
$content .= "<div class='article' id='art-" . $arts['id'] . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

function loadContent(){
   $content = '';
   $pageID = 1;
   $myQuery = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `content`, `keywords`, `description`, `access_level` FROM `tb_articles` WHERE `page_id`='{$pageID}'";
   echo $myQuery;
   $myQuery = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `content`, `keywords`, `description`, `access_level` FROM `tb_articles` WHERE `page_id`=" . $pageID;
   echo $myQuery;
   $articles = mysql_query($myQuery) or die("Error found with the Query" . mysql_error());

        while($arts = mysql_fetch_assoc($articles)){
                $content .= "<div class='article' id='art-" . $arts['id'] . '"';
            $content .= '<h1>' . $arts['name'] . '</h1>';
            $content .= $arts['content'];
            $content .= '</div>';
        }

    return $content;

}
```

Try and tell me, and I'll update with the explanation, if it works.

***UPDATE***

The code has been updated, there are two queries now, execute each one alone and check.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't affect anything.

Comment: ok, put this at the beginning of your page

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Try to run the script again (better after clearing your browser cache)